# Can a schedule with cyclic precedence graph still be serialisable?

Tags: concurrency, database-theory, databases

We know Every conflict serializable schedule is serializable, but not all serializable schedules conflict-serializable. (*) so it means there is at least one serializable schedule that not conflict serializable.

One way of Testing conflict serializability is using Directed graph as mentioned http://www.cburch.com/cs/340/reading/serial/index.html

So if a graph for a schedule has a cycle, this schedule is not conflic serializable. so by using (*) we can say maybe this schedule be a serializable . (i.e we cannot surely determine it's serilizabe or not, just we know it's not conflict serializable)

My inference is right? any idea?

Comment: Could you please add the definition of the "precedence graph"? I just cannot open the link (don't know why). Anyway, for conflict serializability, there exists a *serialization graph* ($SG$) whose nodes are the committed  transactions and whose edges are all $T_i \to T_j$ ($i \neq j$) such that one of $T_i$'s operations precedes and conflicts with one of $T_j$'s operations. The *Serializability Theorem* says that a history $H$ is serializable iff $SG(H)$ is acyclic. Hope it helps. Refer to [the book chapter](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/philbe/chapter2.pdf) for details.

Comment: DEar @hengxin, Please See http://www.cburch.com/cs/340/reading/serial/index.html , it's say all serializable schedules is not conflict-serializable. so testing for conflict serialize  is done with directed graph, so as a result if a graph has a cycle is not conflict serializable and may be not serializable. am i right?

Comment: So are you looking for the necessary and sufficient condition for *serializability* (especially in your EDIT part)? I think we have reached an agreement on *conflict serializability*. For serializability, it is quite complex: It is NP-complete to test whether a history is serializable. (IMO) That is why the html article does not provide a (polynomial) algorithm. The proof for NP-complete can be found [here; Theorem 1](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=322158). It also involves a graph called *polygraph*, but it does not suggest an efficient test (as *SG* does for *conflict serializability*).

Comment: Dear @hengxin, thanks a lot for your effort. i completely edit my question to better understand my question. i'm waiting for your idea. thanks.

Comment: Yes. You cannot infer that a history is not serializable just because it is not conflict-serializable.

Comment: Dear @hengxin, so as a conclusion, it's contradict to  Serializability Theorem that says that a history H is serializable iff SG(H) is acyclic. so we say if we have cycle, it is not conflict-serializable and maybe serializable,  but the theorem is say other things... by if and only if. i means from theorem we have: if there is a cycle, it's not serializable.

Comment: You are talking about two different graphs and two different serializability criteria. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So if a graph for a schedule has a cycle, this schedule is not conflic serializable. so by using (*) we can say maybe this schedule be a serializable

Yes. You cannot infer that a history is not serializable just because it is not conflict-serializable.

> so as a conclusion, it's contradict to Serializability Theorem that says that a history H is serializable iff SG(H) is acyclic.

No. You are talking about two different graphs and two different serializability criteria. And you are confusing them. See my explanation below.

---

The key point here is to tell serializability (SR, for short) from conflict-serializability (CSR, for short) and the polygraph (PG, for short) from serializability graph (SG, for short).

The definition for PG can be found in [this paper](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=322158). The results about SR and polygraph below are also in this paper.

The definition for SG and CSR can be found in [this book chapter](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/philbe/chapter2.pdf).

In the following, I list some key points on your questions.

1. SR $\supset$ CSR. In other words, if a history $h$ is CSR, it must be SR; however, the converse is not valid.
2. The Serializability Theorem is for CSR (*although it is called Serializability Theorem*):

   A history $h$ is CSR $\iff$ SG(h) is acyclic.
3. For SR: a history $h$ is SR $\iff$ PG(h) is acyclic.
4. For a history $h$, SG(h) is more restrictive than PG(h) and leads to an efficient test for CSR. Specifically, we have the following complexity results:

   - Testing whether a history $h$ is CSR (or equivalently, whether SG(h) is acyclic) is polynomial.
   - Testing whether a history $h$ is SR (or equivalently, whether PG(h) is acyclic) is NP-complete.

Notice that the polygraph for a history for SR is quite different from the traditional graphs we learn in class. So don't assume that it is polynomial to test its acyclicity (actually it is *not*).